# The output isn't what i am expecting, the code isn't printing any error and i dont know whats going wrong

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

Vigenere cipher 
Takes in a text and output a cipher version of that text
the user inputs a keyword in the command line and a text for which the user wishes to encrypt. If you're familiar with the Ceasar cipher it's pretty much the same thing except a small minor change, instead of inputting the actual shift value we instead input a keyword and the letters in the keyword would represent the shift value instead.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int shift(char c);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{    
    //checks for alphabetic characters
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(argv[1][i]) == false)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword. \n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        //promting the user for text
        string text = get_string("plaintext:  ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");

        //Intializing variables
        string key = argv[1];
        int l = strlen(key);

        for (int j = 0, k = 0, m = strlen(text); j < m; j++)    
        {
            if (islower(text[j]))
            {
                //lower cap letter enter here 
                printf("%c", 'a' + ( text[j] - 'a' + shift(key[k % l]) ) % 26);
                k++;
            }               
            else if (isupper(text[j]))
            {
                //Upper caps letter enter here
                printf("%c", 'A' + ( text[j] - 'A' + shift(key[k % l]) ) % 26);
                k++;
            } 
            else
            {
                //The rest whatever left enter here 
                printf("%c", text[j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword. \n");
        return 1;
    }
}

//This function calculates the shift value per character 
int shift(char c)
{
    return ( islower(c) - 'a' );
}
```

the problem is that the output isn't what I expect it to be. For instance, if the keyword is 'b' and the text is 'hello' the output must be 'ifmmp' but it's not. I don't know what goes wrong.

Comment: `islower(c)` — do you mean `tolower(c)`?

Comment: voting to close as off-topic, since the problem is a simple typo.

Comment: Fixing function `shift()` now prints the desired output for the example given.